# Starlette's url_for doesn't create links with https scheme behind Nginx (via uvicorn)

Tags: nginx, uvicorn, starlette

I've tried everything:

@Starlette:

```
routes = [
    Mount("/static/", StaticFiles(directory=parent+fs+"decoration"+fs+"static"), name="static"),
    Route(....),
    Route(....),
]
```

@Uvicorn:

```
--forwarded-allow-ips=domain.com
--proxy-headers
```

@url_for:

```
_external=True
_scheme="https"
```

@nginx:

```
proxy_set_header Subdomain $subdomain;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_redirect     http://$http_host/ https://$http_host/;
include proxy_params;
server {
    if ($host = sub.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

If I open a .css or .js link, nginx renders it to https.

When I allow Firefox to ignore the unsafe content, the whole page is rendered correctly at the production server.

Let's encrypt works perfectly with the whole domain, no issues with the certificate.

Comment: Worked for me after adding --forwarded-allow-ips=* to my Dockerfile (I only had --proxy-headers)

Comment: @StevenHuang could you share your solution as an answer so others could benefit from it, thanks Avin

Comment: The answer is the comment I've posted below, it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem after all was the usage of * instead of "*" through bash.

The result was to have all the filenames returned at the FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS parameter instead of the character "*".

Answer (score 3):

I think uvicorn's `--forwarded-allow-ips=domain.com` part needs to have the IP of your Nginx server because it's what's doing the forwarding. (ie change "domain.com" to IP of your nginx server) Note you can also use the environment variable `FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS=*` or `FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS=1.2.3.4` instead (useful if running uvicorn behind gunicorn behind nginx)

For other readers landing here:  I was having the same problem because I failed to configure my "server" config section to actually forward the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers so that uvicorn can get them.   Here's an example of what I needed:

```
 server {
        server_name example.com
        location / {
            proxy_redirect     off;
# These are the critical headers needed by uvicorn to honor HTTPS in url_for :
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
# These are just some other headers you may find useful
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

           ...
        }


    listen 443 ssl;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling with this issue with fastapi and starlette admin based on the above observations i added **--forwarded-allow-ips=*** to my backend service like this

```
  version: '3.3'

  services:
    project_backend:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: backend/backend.demo.dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8005:8000"
        - "8443:443"  # 8443 for HTTPS
      depends_on:
        - project_backend_postgres
      env_file:
        - .docker_env
      networks:
        - backend_network
      volumes:
        - ./certs:/certs
      command: ["uvicorn", "backend.app.app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--forwarded-allow-ips=*"]
```

so all you need to do is add this command to the last of your fastapi service in the docker-compose file

```
command: ["uvicorn", "backend.app.app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--forwarded-allow-ips=*"]
```