# Admin page static data not visible with starlette-admin in a fastapi project with HTTPS

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, starlette

I am working on a FastAPI project that is secured with HTTPS, I was able to dockerize the project and add starlette-admin into the project, It works correctly in my system but when i deploy the admin page static files is not visible, I checked the network tab of the admin page, I found out that the static files used for this page are loaded via HTTP instead of HTTPS so I think that's causing the error, please share a solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and it managed to work with the solution at [Stack Overflow Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66051867/starlettes-url-for-doesnt-create-links-with-https-scheme-behind-nginx-via-uvi)

In summary, you just need to add `--forwarded-allow-ips=*` to your command in docker compose or docker file, like this:

```
 version: '3.3'

  services:
    project_backend:
      build:
        context: .
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      command: ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--forwarded-allow-ips=*"]
```

Comment: Hi Guilherme Goes Zanetti, thanks for shareing my answer with me.. he he..

Comment: Didn't notice that, haha.. But I thought it could be helpful because for me this was the first post while searching in google!